# how to preview a URL thumbnail image in picture box using using?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to show the thumbnail image of url in picture box. here is a code i am trying

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com");
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
}
```

The code is not working, or saying no response

Comment: this contains a useful material it should be mark up world is working on DataMining and SCRAPPING so they are using that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here i have used this tecnique

```
  using System;
  using System.Configuration;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
  using Facebook;
  using System.Net;
   using System.Drawing;
  using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
   using System.Drawing.Imaging;
   using System.IO;


   public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url)
    {
        // This method gets a screenshot of the webpage
        // rendered at its full size (height and width)
        return GenerateScreenshot(url, -1, -1);
    }

    public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
    {
        // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Navigate(url);
        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }


        // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
        wb.Width = width;
        wb.Height = height;

        if (width == -1)
        {
            // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width
            wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
        }

        if (height == -1)
        {
            // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height
            wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
        }

        // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
        wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
        wb.Dispose();

        return bitmap;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pc = textBox1.Text;
        Bitmap thumbnail = GenerateScreenshot(textBox1.Text, 1024, 598);

        thumbnail = GenerateScreenshot(pc);

        // Display Thumbnail in PictureBox control
        pictureBox1.Image = thumbnail;


    }
```